# How make Combobox show all value by click on input?

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, aikau

I have changed `DojoSelect` to `ComboBox` in [this example](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/aikau-tutorials-data-list-1.html). So code for drop down become like that:

```
{
    name: "alfresco/forms/controls/ComboBox",
    config: {
        label: "List Type",
        name: "prop_dl_dataListItemType",
        value: "",
        firstValueIsDefault: false,
        showAllOptionsOnOpen: true,
        optionsConfig: {
                    queryAttribute: "label",
                    labelAttribute: "label",
                    valueAttribute: "value",
            publishTopic: "ALF_GET_FORM_CONTROL_OPTIONS",
            publishPayload: {
                resultsProperty: "options",
                url: url.context + "/proxy/alfresco/api/classes/dl_dataListItem/subclasses",
                itemsAttribute: "",
                labelAttribute: "title",
                valueAttribute: "name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything work with aikau version `1.0.99` (it is important). But `ComboBox` show it's content only when click to right triangle is performed. E.g. when user clicks on to input field nothing happens.

Is there a way to make `alfresco/forms/controls/ComboBox` show options when click to string input is performed?

Answer (score 0):

This was raised within an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/issues/1295) and addressed under this [JIRA](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/AKU-1129) ticket. The fix is described in [this](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/pull/1299) pull request.

Essentially you need to configure `showAllOptionsOnOpen` to be `true`

Comment: Pull request was merged into `1.0.96` aikau version, while I use `1.0.99` And `showAllOptionsOnOpen` is already `true`. :(

Comment: As I see in this merge request, it only added `showAllOptionsOnOpen` field. But question is not about show all options only. The question is about **where** to click on `Combobox` to **see** these options. For now user have to click on [triangle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Ic_arrow_drop_down_36px.svg/1024px-Ic_arrow_drop_down_36px.svg.png), while it is needed to click onto input, where text is typed. Users do not konow about inputs or triangles they just click and see that it does not work. :( It is especial important when input "part" is very long.

Comment: We have a unit test for this. Also, if you go to this Sandpit page: https://aikau-sandpit.alfresco.com/aikau-sandpit/page/na/ws/MultiSelectInput and swap MultiSelectInput for ComboBox in the first example and add the showAllOptionsOnOpen configuration attribute and click the "Update Preview" button you'll be able to see that it does work (I've just tried this).

Comment: It's filtered based on the type ahead - so the options shown match the query  being provided.

Comment: No it does not work. :) `swap MultiSelectInput for ComboBox in the first example and add the showAllOptionsOnOpen configuration attribute` and then remove `"value": "foam_strawberries",` then click "Update Preview". You will see empty Combobox which does not show you any values when you click on text input.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, because I just tried again and it works as I described. When you remove the value and you start typing you get the results. If you have a value selected and you click the down arrow you see all the options. Why not try again.